# Add space at end of a constant char in ABAP

Tags: char, abap, space

I need to declare this constant:

```
CONSTANTS: const_sep(3) type c value ' - '.
```

but with this command, ending space is not considered. How can I declare this constant value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: You don't. When working with fields of `TYPE C` (which are always fixed-length fields), the system always trims trailing whitespace. Switch to a `TYPE STRING` if you need to keep the trailing whitespace, and use the correct delimiters for strings:

```
CONSTANTS co_sep TYPE string VALUE ` - `.
                             "     ^   ^
```